# OPENPYXL: write new sheets

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas, openpyxl

I have a workbook created in openpyxl and am trying to populate sheets with df's from queries. However, when I open the xlsx the sheets have been created but all of the queries are concatenated into the first sheet and the other sheets are blank. What is wrong?

Here is the code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

# Create the hospital_ranking workbook
hospital_ranking = Workbook()
dest_filename1 = "hospital_ranking.xlsx"

ws1 = hospital_ranking.active
ws1.title = "Nationwide"

from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

# Write the nationwide query to ws1
for r in dataframe_to_rows(national_results, index = False, header = True):
    ws1.append(r)

for cell in ws1['A'] + ws1[1]:
    cell.style = 'Pandas'

hospital_ranking.save(filename = staging_dir + dest_filename1)

# Create the worksheet for each focus state

# CA
ws2 = hospital_ranking.create_sheet(title = 'California')
ws2 = hospital_ranking.active

# Write the CA query to ws2
for r in dataframe_to_rows(ca_results, index = False, header = True):
    ws2.append(r)

for cell in ws2['A'] + ws2[1]:
    cell.style = 'Pandas'

hospital_ranking.save(filename = staging_dir + dest_filename1)
```

Comment: *information in the spreadsheet is wrong* ... What is wrong? Are columns mixed up? Rows removed? Entirely different data? missing data? Your code looks to be creating empty state named sheets but no data.

Comment: You don't want the indexes but you deliberately set them to `True`. Maybe you should read the code a bit more when you copy & paste it.

Comment: @Parfait - the spreadsheet is filled with entirely different data from a spreadsheet loaded into the program higher up in the code

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the new worksheets not being created was the following mistake:

```
ws2 = hospital_ranking.create_sheet(title = 'California')
ws2 = hospital_ranking.active
```

For each sheet. This does not work, I changed the code to:

```
ws2 = hospital_ranking.create_sheet(title = 'California')
ws2 = hospital_ranking.get_sheet_by_name('California')
```

And all of the sheets were populated correctly. The problem was that `wb.active` does not actually call the sheet.

Comment: Works fine, thanks you've saved me. the get_sheet_by_name is deprecated though. the new method is

wss = hospital_rangking['California']

Answer (score 2):

**First:**

If you want to remove 'index' while writing to the excel worksheet, use

```
index=False
```

instead of

```
index=True
```

in your code.

**Second:**
You've mentioned you're saving each dataframe into a new worksheet. However, I do not see you doing that in your code.

You're creating the worksheets, named "California", "Florida" and so on but I do not seem anywhere in your script you're populating them like you do for the worksheet ws1, i.e.,

```
for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
    ws2.append(r);
```

Followed by,

```
for cell in ws2['A'] + ws2[1]:
    cell.style = "Pandas"
```

Eventually save by

```
wb.save(filename=dest_filename);
```

To do this, you can eventually loop the whole depending on how you create your pandas dataframe from the query.

**For you to debug:**
Make sure your query returns what you intended and being stored properly in the pandas dataframe. May be you can evaluate pandas dataframe intermediately before writing.

What do you mean by, "The sheet does not have correct information in it?" Could you please elaborate on this?

**Saving to specific directory:**

```
targetDir = "<Absolute path to your target directory>"

wb.save(filename=targetDir+dest_filename);
```

Forexample:

```
targetDir="/home/rb/staging"
```

<s>wb.save(filename=targetDir+dest_filename);</s>

```
wb.save(filename=os.path.join("staging/")+dest_filename);
```

(Using string concatenation)

Comment: @RusselB the queries run perfect and the dataframes are being populated correctly. I havent added the code to populate the other sheets in the workbook because the first sheet isnt being populated correctly. Once I get the first sheet to work- I will copy and ammend the code to fill the other sheets with the approriate dataframes

Comment: How can I save to a specific directory?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it just changed the filename to "staginghospital_ranking" and the file remains in the working directory instead of the "staging" dr.... i edited the question though to reflect your comment on multiple sheets (which are not working)

Comment: i think for the path i need to use something like os.path.join("staging" + filename) but I got an unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: I was able to save the workbook to the appropriate directory. However, it only contains the "Nationwide" sheet. The other sheets are missing.

Comment: how can I write multiple sheets? My current code is concatenating all the dataframes into the first sheet, leaving the others empty(but created)

Comment: To answer this, how are you storing your query results? All the data retrieved in a single query? or each query for each dataframe(ca_results, fl_results and so on?

Comment: Each query is returned in a seperate dataframe (ca_results,fl_results,etc)

Answer (score 0):

Adding as another answer, as the question has been changed and for readability of the solution,

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import numpy as np
import os

wb = Workbook();
dest_filename='myWorkbook.xlsx';

## City names - array
cityNames = ['Nation wide','California', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Michigan'];

# Creating dicitonary of dataframes
dfDict = {};

for  i in range(len(cityNames)):
newData = np.random.randn(3,3); #Substitute at this point your dataframe building query from a list of query strings may be
dfDict[i] = pd.DataFrame(newData); # Or you can do it inline @ this point


def writeSheets(cityList):
    for n in range(len(dfDict)):
        ws = wb.create_sheet(title=cityList[n], index=n);
        for r in dataframe_to_rows(dfDict[n], index=False, header=True):
            ws.append(r);

        for cell in ws['A']+ws[1]:
            cell.style = "Pandas";
    wb.save(filename=os.path.join("/home/russellb/russell/Python/"+dest_filename));

writeSheets(cityNames);
```

Comment: I already have the dataframes, but im not sure how to add each one to the dictionary. Moreover, the syntax you have used in def writeSheets(citylist) is exactly the same as what I am using already - so Im not sure how the sheets would be added to the workbook any differently (or at all in this case)

Comment: If you have them already, create a list of it and loop them as shown above. As to the sheets, I am not setting active sheets. May be you can check what it does to get an understanding. Have tried running my script?